# E-mail header extraction using C substring program gives wrong output. Why?

Tags: c, substring

My goal is to extract subject field contents from a text file that contains an e-mail header informations and copy the contents in the subject field into a new text file. But the program gives the wrong output. The program I created (`f1.c`) in C is given below. I omitted my program's header, variable delaration sections:

```
ifp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
ofp = fopen(argv[2],"w");

if (ifp==NULL)    
{    
    printf("\nFile cannot be opened\n");
    return;
}
else
{
    while(fscanf(ifp,"%s",buf)!=EOF)
    {
        printf("%s\n",buf);
        if (strstr(buf,"Subject:")==0)
        {
            //fprintf(ofp,"%s","hai");
            fscanf(ifp,"%[^\n]s",buf);
            fprintf(ofp,"%s",buf);
        }
        else
        {
                fgets(buf,15,ifp);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(ofp);
    fclose(ifp);
}
```

Here is the input file I am using: (`spam.txt.`)

```
To:hhhhgdg
Subject:get that new car 8434
hi,how are you
keeping good?
```

After compilation and running this program:

```
princy@PRINCY:~/minipjt$ cc f1.c
princy@PRINCY:~/minipjt$ ./a.out spam.txt b2.c
```

The output file I am getting (`b2.c`) contains:

```
 are you
 good?
```

The output file actually should contain only the line given below:

```
get that new car 8434
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Correction:**

It will make things easier if you use **line-oriented** input instead of **word-oriented input**. For example `getline` or `fgets` (I prefer `getline`). Using line oriented input to capture each line in its entirety makes parsing the file for **Subject:** and handling the resulting string much easier.

For example, try:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: insufficient input. Usage: %s input_file output_file\n",
                 argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *ifp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    FILE *ofp = fopen(argv[2],"w");

    char *buf = NULL;    /* forces getline to allocate space for buf */
    ssize_t read = 0;
    size_t n = 0;
    char *ptr = NULL;

    if (ifp==NULL)    
    {    
        printf("\nFile cannot be opened\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while ((read = getline (&buf, &n, ifp)) != -1)
        {
            printf("%s\n",buf);

            if ((ptr=strstr(buf,"Subject:")) != 0)
                fprintf(ofp,"%s",ptr);      /* use (ptr + 9) to trim 'Subject:` away */
        }
    }

    if (buf)        /* free memory allocated by getline for buf */
        free (buf);
    fclose(ofp);
    fclose(ifp);

    return 0;
}
```

If your goal is to only capture the contents of the line after **Subject:**, then you can simply advance the pointer `ptr` to after the space following the `:` with `ptr += 9;`, then output to your file.

Let me know if you have any questions.

---

**Addendum - Line After Subject:**

To get the line after subject, you could simply continue in the same `if` block and read the next line using `getline` again. Replace the existing code-block with:

```
            if ((ptr=strstr(buf,"Subject:")) != 0) {
                fprintf(ofp,"%s",ptr);  /* use (ptr + 9) to trim 'Subject:` away */

                /* get line after Subject */
                if ((read = getline (&buf, &n, ifp)) != -1)
                    fprintf(ofp,"Line after Subject: %s",buf);
            }
```

Comment: It worked out.I needed to get line after subject.By changing the ptr to ptr+8, I could get the required answer.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Added **Addendum** for getting line after `Subject:`. Let me know if that is what you needed.

Comment: I need to extract subject(it can have multiple lines) into one text file,other header fields of an email into another text file,finally the body into a third text file.what changes should make in this program?

Comment: Very few. You already have the subject line, so that can stay as is. Basically, you will open 2 additional `FILE *` steams - one for remaining_header and one for body. For the remaining header contents, just add an `else` after `if ((ptr=strstr(buf,"Subject:")) != 0) {...}` and write those line to the header file until you reach (generally the first blank line following header) the start of the body. Then just change to writing to the body file. **Note:** you will need to check for multi-part messages (attachments) which can add sections to the header and after the body. Try it, report back.

Comment: subject field may not be the first line of a email text file.so if we read subject first into a subject text file ,then the remaining fields into header text file(until blank line which separates body),in that case fields above subject will not be written into the same header file.but those also should be written.how?